# Question about vector space and Bidual Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, $S \subset V$ and $\Phi: V \to V^{**}$ the isomorphism given by $\Phi(v) = \phi_v$, where $\phi_v:V \to F$ is given by $\phi_v(f) = f(v).$ Show that $S$ is a generator of $\Phi^{-1}((S^{0})^{0})$.

Addictional information: $S^0= \{f:V \to F: f(s) = 0, \forall s \in S\}$ and therefore $(S^{0})^{0} = \{g:V^{*} \to F: g(f) = 0, \forall f \in S^{0} \}$.

So, I have no Idea how to prove that.

I know that if $v \in \Phi^{-1}((S^{0})^{0})$, then $\Phi(v) \in (S^0)^0$ and $\Phi(v)=\phi_v$ where $\phi_v: V^{*} \to F$ is given by $\phi(f) = f(v)$. Since $\phi_v \in (S^{0})^{0}$ we have $\phi_v(f) = 0$, for all $f \in S^0$.

I can't see how it implies that $v$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $S$.

Can you help me?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582401/question-concerning-the-definition-and-property-of-an-annihilator-sec-3-5-linea) help?

Comment: I know those theorems but it doesn't help (I guess)

Comment: The theorems say exactly what you are trying to prove: that if you start with $S$, then $S$ spans the annihilator of $S^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{span} S  = \Phi^{-1}((S^0)^0)$ if and only if $\Phi(\operatorname{span} S) = (S^0)^0$. Now, as $\Phi(S) \subseteq  \Phi(\operatorname{span} S)$ and $\Phi(\operatorname{span} S)$ is a subspace of $V^{**}$ that contains $\Phi(S)$, it follows that $\operatorname{span}(\Phi(S)) \subseteq \Phi(\operatorname{span} S)$. Also, the inclusion $\Phi(\operatorname{span} S) \subseteq  \operatorname{span}(\Phi(S))$ it is easy to check.

So, it is enough to prove that $(S^0)^0 = \operatorname{span}(\Phi(S))$. You can check my proof of this fact right [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611889/how-to-prove-that-s00-operatornamespan-psis-where-psi-v/3612708#3612708).

Comment: I got It, thank you.